# Highstock setExtremes with a custom range selector button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In highstock range selector I added a custom range selector button (named: my dates) and would like to set a custom extremes when this button is called. I know it works if you put simple button outside the chart and call: chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(30,80);.

But my scenario is different I want to add a button beside "1m 1y All" range selector buttons, and want that new button to set a custom extremes dates. Using xAxis events setExtremes, does not seems to work unless I am missing something. http://jsfiddle.net/Aeaz3/1/

```
$(function() {

  $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        type: '',
                        count: 2,
                        text: 'My dates'
                    },{
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    }, {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1d'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        xAxis: {    
                        events:{
                            setExtremes: function(e) {
                                  var xMin = e.min;
                                 var xMax = e.max; 
                                var zmRange = computeTickInterval(xMin, xMax);
                                    this.chart.xAxis[0].options.tickInterval =zmRange;
                                    this.chart.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;


                            },
                        }
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setExtremes` callback:

> Fires when the minimum and maximum is set for the axis, either by
>   calling the .setExtremes() method or by selecting an area in the
>   chart. The this keyword refers to the axis object itself. One
>   parameter, event, is passed to the function. This contains common
>   event information based on jQuery or MooTools depending on which
>   library is used as the base for Highcharts.

**So it's not really meant to be used to set extremes but is rather a notification when something else does some extreme setting.**

That said, I still think it is possible to leverage it for your use case by catching the call when your button is clicked and then resetting it to your custom range:

```
xAxis: {    
    events:{
        if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton" && 
            e.rangeSelectorButton.text == "My dates"){
            // it is your button that caused this,
            // so setExtrememes to your custom
            // have to do in timeout to let
            // highcharts finish processing events...
            setTimeout(function(){
                Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(1198681756385,1368144000000)
            }, 1);
        }
    }
},
```

Updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aeaz3/3/).

Answer (score -2):

One approach would be to modify highstock to use the values of e.min and e.max if they are changed in your event handler. This can be done by modifying 3 lines of code.

in highstock.src.js line 7447 (in version 2.0.4). The method is called setExtremes.

Change:

```
fireEvent(axis, 'setExtremes', eventArguments, function () { // the default event handler

        axis.userMin = newMin;
        axis.userMax = newMax;
```

To:

```
fireEvent(axis, 'setExtremes', eventArguments, function (event) { // the default event handler

        axis.userMin = event.min;
        axis.userMax = event.max;
```

And now changing e.min or e.max in the xAxis.setExtremes event will work. (Don't call setExtremes())